# Boolean operators: can I use AND, OR in `\ifthenelse`? How?

Tags: conditionals

Can I use AND, OR in `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package? If so, can you show me examples and links to documentation? This would make my life easier.

Comment: `\OR` and `\AND` see `texdoc ifthen`

Comment: There is always Knuth, Computers and Typesetting.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It exists, but it won't tell you anything about `\ifthenelse`

Comment: besides [**`ifthen`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ifthen), you should also take a look at [**`etoolbox`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox).

Comment: To add to @henrique , for `etoolbox`, you would want to look for `ifboolexpr` (and others) with their `and` and `or` (and more) operators.

Answer (score 32):

```
\ifthenelse{1>2 \OR 3=3}{yes}{no}

\ifthenelse{1>2 \AND 3=3}{yes}{no}
```

produces

```
yes
no
```